# Remember enable -n in child shell

Tags: bash, shell-builtin

I have have disabled `echo` `built-in` so that `echo` will be searched in `$PATH`. I have used `enable -n` command for this. Please see below.

```
$ type echo
echo is a shell builtin
$ enable -n echo
$ type echo
echo is /bin/echo
```

But when I open a child shell from the current shell, again the built-in `echo` is used. Please see below.

```
$ type echo
echo is /bin/echo
$ bash
$ # Now I am in child shell
$ type echo
echo is a shell builtin
```

Is there any way I can preserve this setting in the child shell as well, so that in child shell also `echo` would be sought in `$PATH` (i.e. `enable -n echo` would remain in effect)?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are two ways.  One for interactive and one for non-interactive bash shells.

For interactive bash shells, put the command `enable -n echo` in your `$HOME/.bashrc` file.  Then all interactive shells will use the external echo.

I do *not* recommend this for non-interactive shells, but to do it, you would set the environment variable `BASH_ENV` to any file containing the line `enable -n echo`.  Then all non-interactive bash shells will run the file named by the BASH_ENV file, thereby causing them to use the external echo.

Answer (score 0):

That ("enable -n") appears to be a [bash-specific feature](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-Builtins).  You could put the

```
enable -n echo
```

in the corresponding shell initialization script, e.g., `~/.bashrc`, so that it would affect each shell that you invoke.

Comment: Not working for me..its not being propagated to the subshells..